# Does bash really truncate output redirection files at opening?

Tags: bash, pipe, stdout, io-redirection

From what I've read, bash is supposed to truncate files when it opens them. However after I run the command `echo hello > file1 | ls > file1 > file2`, sometimes file1 contains "hello", sometimes it doesn't contain anything. It is a really weird behavior, and I can't even find out what is the pattern, it seems aleatory. Here is for example the result of a few tries in my bash, sometimes deleting the first output file before, sometimes not:

```
bash-3.2$ echo hello > output2 | ls > output2 > output3
bash-3.2$ cat output2
hello
bash-3.2$ rm output2
bash-3.2$ echo hello > output2 | ls > output2 > output3
bash-3.2$ cat output2
bash-3.2$ echo hello > output2 | ls > output2 > output3
bash-3.2$ cat output2
hello
bash-3.2$ rm output2
bash-3.2$ echo hello > output2 | ls > output2 > output3
bash-3.2$ cat ouput2
cat: ouput2: No such file or directory
bash-3.2$ cat output2
bash-3.2$ echo hello > output2 | ls > output2 > output3
bash-3.2$ cat output2
hello
```

I need to reproduce bash behavior in C so I really need to see what is the pattern here, why files are sometimes truncated and sometimes not

EDIT: I know this command makes no sense in itself, I just need to reproduce bash's behavior in C with any command, even the most stupid one, so I need to know how it works here. I just typed a command easy to understand with no context to illustrate my problem

Comment: Use `>` **or** `|` to redirect stdout.

Comment: What you do is not meaningful. First you pipe after a redirection to a file, which is not reasonable and has no effect. Second, `ls` by default ignores its standard input, it could accept only arguments (e.g. with xargs)

Comment: @Cyrus I know this command makes no sense in itself, I just need to reproduce bash's behavior in C with any command so I need to know how it works here. I just typed a command easy to understand with no context to illustrate my problem

Comment: @thanasisp I know, cf my edit, I just observe that sometimes output files are not truncated, which is bothering me because everyone seems to say that the output files are always truncated at opening

Comment: When you a pipeline like `... | ...` the right and left hand side are run in *parallel*; sometimes the left one ends even before the right one started, sometimes they start pretty much at the same time on separate processor cores, etc. Trying to reason about which one should should have its side effects first is a complete waste of time.

Comment: You can easily reproduce bash's behaviour in C by calling `fork()` and not knowing which of the child or the parent will run first.

Comment: @user414777 ok thanks now I understand, so I guess I will stick with this answer and accept that my implementation cannot always have the same result as bash